# Git - extract subfolders of repository into new repositories

Tags: files, filesystems, git, file-management

I have a folder structure like this, with all folders and files within one `git` repository:

```
├── folder-01
│   └── script.sh
├── folder-02
│   └── script.sh
├── folder-03
│   └── script.sh
├── folder-04
│   └── script.sh
└── .git
```

is it possible to extract the folders from the main repository into separate repositories, each within one folder, so it would look like this:

```
├── folder-01
│   ├── .git
│   └── script.sh
├── folder-02
│   ├── .git
│   └── script.sh
├── folder-03
│   ├── .git
│   └── script.sh
└── folder-04
    ├── .git
    └── script.sh
```

I would be also interested in the command for doing it manually one by one.

Comment: Read about git submodules; this is what I believe you want.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco thanks for the hint, it looks like `git filter-branch` is doing what I want though I did not find a batch solution doing it for all subfolders...